# SharePoint 2013 - Get sum of number fields and lookup field with Javascript

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I'm creating a list that helps track employees projected hours they spend on projects as well as holiday, training and vacation hours.  However the holiday field is part of a look up from another list.  I also need the totals to show as employees fill out the form, not after they save it.  So the Calculate Column does not work for this particular form.  I know JavaScript can help but do not know how to have it calculate the regular columns and the lookup column.  I will also then need to compare and validate against another lookup column.  Can anyone help write that code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following example for your reference.

1.Create a custom list, and add lookup column "holiday", number columns "training","vacation" and "totals" into list.

2.Add the following code into script editor web part in new/edit form page.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction() { 
    var holiday= $("select[title='holiday'] option:selected").text();
    var training= $("input[title='training']").val();
    var vacation=$("input[title='vacation']").val();
    var totals=parseInt(holiday)+parseInt(training)+parseInt(vacation);
    alert("Totals:"+totals);
    $("input[title='totals']").val(totals);
    return true;
}
</script>
```

3.Click the save button we can see the "totals" value.

[image]